# Managed Bean Annotation doesn't work in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, jboss, managed-bean

I've encoutered strange issue with annotations in bean.

**index.xhtml** content:

`<h:outputText value="#{ejb.helloWorld}" />`

**Ejb.java** content:

```
package bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

    @ManagedBean(name="ejb")
    @SessionScoped
    public class Ejb implements Serializable
    {
        public String getHelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
```

From what we see above i should be able to call bean method... but i can't, it will work **only** if i manage bean in `faces-config.xml` file with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd" 
          version="2.0">

          <managed-bean>
              <managed-bean-name>ejb</managed-bean-name>
              <managed-bean-class>bean.Ejb</managed-bean-class>
              <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
          </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

**Questions**:

1. Why i have encountered such situation ?
2. How to resolve this issue ?

I'm using:

- `JSF 2.0` (imported to lib)
- `JBoss Server 4.2`

Comment: For JSF 2.0, you really should be using JBoss AS7 as it's the JEE6 certified one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My wild guess is that JSF 1.2 bundled by default with JBoss 4.2 is used (JBoss might not care about JSF version). As a result annotations are ignored, faces-config.xml file is used.

Try to use configuration suggested [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aEvB_s1KraVIJ%3astinkycheese.ajexperience.com/2010/10/jboss-5-with-jsf-2-on-a-per-app-basis/%20&cd=1&hl=pl&ct=clnk&gl=pl) (thats's google cached page).